# Sharepoint 2010 Accidently deleted Tasks field Description. Can't get it back

Tags: 2010, tasks, outlook, task-list

I have been trying to find a way to restore the Tasks list Description column in the task list. The reason I need this column is so that it will sync with Outlook Tasks. The column can't just be named "Description" and have all the same settings.

At some point that column was deleted and now I cannot find it in the site columns or anywhere else to pick existing columns from. Description is a standard/system task column so it obviously can't be replaced by a column with the same settings. It needs to be the exact column that the Task List is created with.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer ?